# Roo spreadsheet uploading OLE2 signature is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, spreadsheet

Right so I've checked out Roo. Great gem and all and have a really basic application that doesn't have no models. And basic controller, class and view and I can't seem to get a spreadsheet to upload as I am getting `OLE2 signature is invalid` error. I have the following basic setup

**Controller**

```
class SpreadsheetServiceController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create    
    parser = SpreadsheetTagService.new(params[:spreadsheet][:file])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.all {render :json => 'Done'}
    end
  end
end
```

**SpreadsheetTagService**

```
 class SpreadsheetTagService 
  include Roo

  def initialize(uploaded_file)
    @tmp_destination = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/tag-import.xls"
    @file_path = save_file_to_tmp(uploaded_file)
    @file = File.new(@file_path)
    read_file(@file)
  end 

  private 
    def save_file_to_tmp(uploaded_file)
      FileUtils.mv(uploaded_file.tempfile.path, @tmp_destination )
      @tmp_destination
    end

    def read_file(file)
      @spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
      @spreadsheet.each_with_pagename do |name,sheet|    
        Rails.logger.debug( sheet )
      end    
    end

    def open_spreadsheet(file)
      case File.extname(file.path)
        when ".csv" then Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
        when ".xls" then Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
        when ".xlsx" then Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
        else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
      end
    end

end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_tag spreadsheetupload_url, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `.xls` format use `.xlsx` format.then it will work.

For me it's working.

Answer (score 4):

This article was quite useful:

http://atomicules.co.uk/2009/07/17/roo-and-ole2-signature-is-invalid.html

FullText:

> If you get an "Ole::Storage::FormatError: OLE2 signature is invalid"
>   error when reading an Excel spreadsheet using Roo it can probably be
>   solved by resaving the spreadsheet (unfortunately using Excel) and
>   making sure it is saving it as "Microsoft Office Excel Workbook
>   (*.xls)", etc and not something odd.
>
> I had two spreadsheets that had the .xls extension, but seems they
>   were masquerading; when doing a Save As on them one was actually in a
>   "Text (tab delimited)" format and the other in a "Web Page" HTML
>   format. These were system generated files, so I guess that explains
>   their odd form.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because links can rot.

Comment: Link suggests resaving the file as XLS, for certain, could be the fix. Worked for me. At the Save As... prompt, Excel was suggesting that my file was actually XML.