# Ole::Storage::FormatError: OLE2 signature is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

I want to read an Excel File in my Rails Application.

This is how I open my Excel file and read it.

```
doc = Spreadsheet.open('./try.xls', "r")
sheet = doc.worksheet 0
sheet.each do |row|
array_rows << row.to_a
end
```

I have it as a rake task.When I try to Read this file it throws an error.

```
Ole::Storage::FormatError: OLE2 signature is invalid
```

What is happening? what should I do?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990116/roo-spreadsheet-uploading-ole2-signature-is-invalid

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The .xls file must be saved in EXCEL 2003 format. So 
    File-->Save As
    from All Formats dropdown select the Excel year 2003

This solved my problem

Comment: but what would you do if your client uploads the file and it is in .xlsx which is a new format which is from 2007?

Answer (score 2):

On Mac I had to save it as Excel 97-2004(.xls) to get it to work